# awk function syntax error?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Can someone see why I get

```
awk: cmd. line:8:   function mma(num) {
awk: cmd. line:8:   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:8:   function mma(num) {
awk: cmd. line:8:                     ^ syntax error
```

from this script?

```
echo "0.24 0.21 0.22 1/1282 10953" | awk '{

  min=""
  max=""
  avg=""

  # find min, max, avg
  function mma(num) {
    if(min==""){min=max=$1};
    if($1>max) {max=$1};
    if($1<min) {min=$1};
    total+=$1;
    count+=1;
    avg=total/count;
  }

  mma($1)
  mma($2)
  mma($3)

  print avg, max, min
}'
```

Comment: There are few points to be noted here eg--> `while` loop doesn't have `done` in it to complete it's syntax.

Comment: Your function cannot be defined in an action from a `(pattern){ action }` rule of your `awk` script.

Comment: If you could show us sample input and sample output in CODE TAGS in your post we could try to help you more here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks. Now fixed.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting, kindly post the expected output too in your post.

Comment: @kvantour I don't know what that means. Can you post how you would write it?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting I have added an answer explaining it a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitions of functions can appear anywhere between the rules of an awk program. From the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_15) :

> The awk language also provides user-defined functions. Such functions can be defined as:
>
> ```
> function name([parameter, ...]) { statements }
> ```
>
> A function **can be referred to anywhere** in an awk program; in particular, its use can precede its definition. The scope of a function is global. <snip>  Function definitions **can appear anywhere** in the program where a pattern-action pair is allowed.

This means a valid awk program looks like :

```
( pattern1 ) { action1 }
function name([parameter, ...]) { statements }
( pattern2 ) { action2 }
...
```

In your original code, you wrote the incorrect

```
( pattern ) { function name([paramter, ...]) { statements }
             action }
```

So the corrected version of your `awk` part would be:

```
awk 'function mma(num) {
        if(min==""){min=max=$1};
        if($1>max) {max=$1};
        if($1<min) {min=$1};
        total+=$1;
        count+=1;
        avg=total/count;
     }
     { min=""; max=""; avg=""
       mma($1); mma($2); mma($3)
       print avg, max, min
     }'
```

---

**update:** from the comments, it might be more useful to use

```
awk '{ avg=($1+$2+$3)/3; min=avg; max=avg;
       min=($1<min) ? $1 : min; max=($1>max) ? $1 : max
       min=($2<min) ? $2 : min; max=($2>max) ? $2 : max
       min=($3<min) ? $3 : min; max=($3>max) ? $3 : max
       print avg,max, min } ' /proc/loadavg
```

However, this is questionable as taking the average of averages is very ...

Also interesting might be the `sar` command.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting this works without errors on my side, I am however a bit puzzled what the code does or its intentions should be. As your function argument `num` is never used. By default, this will always return the first element of `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Ok, so that might be the problem then. I though the arguments for a function could be anything. I just called it `num` and thought it would be `$1` inside the function definition. But that is not the case?

Comment: So I guess all `$1` in the function should be `num`?

Comment: `$i` always refers to field number `i`.

Comment: Ok, so that it one bug then in my script. There must be something else as well, as it still gives the same error.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting could you please explain your intentions for this script. Since `/proc/loadavg` shows the average load for the first 1,5 and 10 minutes of the system. Do you want to find the min/max/avg of these 3 numbers? Or do you want to have the min/max/avg per field of the continuously updated `/proc/loadavg`. If the latter, then this script will not work as intended.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting The first or the latter?

Comment: Sorry, the first.

Comment: wrt `I get the same error as with my script` - no you do not. It is not possible for the script in this answer to produce the same syntax error as in your question. If you're getting an error then tell us what that error is. You seem to be confusing awk syntax with shell syntax in some ways - awk is far more like C than it is like shell. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: I always point out that the K in AWK stands for  Kernighan.  Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie wrote C.